# Implement "Open Containing Folder" and highlight file

Tags: c#, .net, file, windows-explorer

This can be a handy functionality to have in a program that works with files/folders. It's easy enough to actually open the containing folder using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( *path to folder* );
```

...but how do I go about actually selecting the target file within that parent folder? If I use the Process.Start method it actually attempts to open the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Folder and Select the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/open-folder-and-select-the-file)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to [Windows Explorer Command-Line Options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457) you just need to start an `explorer` process with `/select` parameter.

For instance, '`explorer /select,c:\Windows`' will open a window with `c:\windows` folder selected.

So simply `Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select," + filename)` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks!  To my surprise, when Directory Opus is installed, this is used instead, despite the explicit reference to explorer.exe.  This is a good thing.

Comment: @Crosbie that's because Directory Opus hooks into explorer and intercepts calls to it.

Answer (score 5):

Execute Explorer.exe with `/select, "filename"` command line argument

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
    "explorer.exe", 
    string.Format("/select, \"{0}\"", filename));
```

Comment: This won't work because `select`'s parameter should be comma-separated rather than space-separated

Comment: Just for a note, quoting (`\"{0}\"`) is not necessary because `explorer` will treat anything after `/select,` as a path (ignoring starting and ending whitespace) -- so '`/select,{0}`' is enough...

Answer (score 1):

Containing folder, Self directory is represented in many ways!!! 
Simple 2 ways are `.` and, `.\.` no idea what is the difference!.. :D 
From DOS and bat files... `Start .` or `Start .\.` (Y)

Try... these 2 works, but check whether this is the solution u expect!

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @".\.");
```

Or

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @".");
```

-

- Sometimes the application is run from a temp directory or a different dir (eg: in Sandbox... or while being scanned by antivirus... etc. :)