# How to open Explorer with a specific file selected?

Tags: c#, winapi, vbscript

I would like to code a function to which you can pass a file path, for example:

```
C:\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER\FILE.TXT
```

and it would open Windows Explorer with the folder containing the file and then select this file inside the folder. (Similar to the "Show In Folder" concept used in many programs.)

How can I do this?

Comment: Also, is it possible to select multiple files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement "Open Containing Folder" and highlight file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829501/implement-open-containing-folder-and-highlight-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a folder in explorer and selecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/334630/11585798)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Easiest way without using Win32 shell functions is to simply launch explorer.exe with the `/select` parameter. For example, launching the process

`explorer.exe /select,"C:\Folder\subfolder\file.txt"`

will open a new explorer window to C:\Folder\subfolder with file.txt selected.

If you wish to do it programmatically without launching a new process, you'll need to use the shell function [`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is what the `/select` command to explorer.exe will use internally. Note that this requires the use of PIDLs, and can be a real PITA if you are not familiar with how the shell APIs work.

Here's a complete, programmatic implementation of the `/select` approach, with path cleanup thanks to suggestions from @Bhushan and @tehDorf:

```
public bool ExploreFile(string filePath) {
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) {
        return false;
    }
    //Clean up file path so it can be navigated OK
    filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", string.Format("/select,\"{0}\"", filePath));
    return true;
}
```

Reference: [Explorer.exe Command-line switches](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html)

Comment: You need a comma after the select like this explorer.exe /select, "c:\folder\subfolder\file.txt

Comment: What are the downsides of launching a new process?

Comment: @Gusdor Nothing, really. Unless you have enabled launched folder windows in a separate process in your folder view options (by default, it's disabled) this does not actually launch a new process. It goes through the motions, but an existing explorer.exe instance will be called to handle the request instead of launching a new process in a separate memory space. If you're calling this code a lot, it's certainly more efficient and less wasteful to use `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` during the opening sequence, though.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi Instead of using a `Regex` to clean up the file path, you can use `filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(filePath);`. It will normalize the directory separators and it will also resolve relative paths, such as if you pass in something like `@"..\some\relative\file\path.txt"` or `@"C:\Some\relative\..\file\path.txt"`. You could also update the example to use the new string interpolation: `Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"/select,\"{filePath}\"");`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the filename itself contains a coma.

Comment: The downside of launching explorer is that it is slower than `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` and that it tends to open the explorer in the background. So I recommend `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`.

Answer (score 10):

The *supported* method since Windows XP (i.e. not supported on Windows 2000 or earlier) is [**SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems):

```
void OpenFolderAndSelectItem(String filename)
{
   // Parse the full filename into a pidl
   PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
   SFGAO flags;
   SHParseDisplayName(filename, null, out pidl, 0, out flags);
   try 
   {
      // Open Explorer and select the thing
      SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidl, 0, null, 0);
   }
   finally 
   {
      // Use the task allocator to free to returned pidl
      CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @Mahmoud Al-Qudsi's answer. when he says "launching the process", this is what worked for me:

```
// assume variable "path" has the full path to the file, but possibly with / delimiters
for ( int i = 0 ; path[ i ] != 0 ; i++ )
{
    if ( path[ i ] == '/' )
    {
        path[ i ] = '\\';
    }
}
std::string s = "explorer.exe /select,\"";
s += path;
s += "\"";
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;
STARTUPINFOA startupInfo;
ZeroMemory( &startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo) );
startupInfo.cb = sizeof( STARTUPINFOA );
ZeroMemory( &processInformation, sizeof( processInformation ) );
CreateProcessA( NULL, (LPSTR)s.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation );
```

Comment: The question is tagged C#, this is a C++ answer, which might be correct, but not relevant for people looking for a C#/.NET solution.

Comment: I vote up because this method does the trick in C# as well, just use Process.Start("explorer.exe " + "/select, " + '\"'+ filePath.Replace('/', '\\') + '\"');  Forward slashes should be replaced with backslashes.