# Highlighting the newly created files of application instance while browsing the folder path

Tags: c#, wpf, file, directory, process.start

While navigating to the folder through Process.Start(folderPath), I wish to see the newly created files as highlighted/Selected. Everytime I open the instance of my wpf application, there are some Log files which get created at a specified folder path. I want to see those new created files as highlighted/Selected.

```
        private void ShowFolder()
        {

           //Open the folder path through Process.Start 
           //sLogFolderPath is the folder path where log files are created

           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(sLogFolderPath);


         //When folder is opened through Process.Start, 
        //I would like to see the newly created files as highlighted.

        }
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680415/how-to-open-explorer-with-a-specific-file-selected)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a folder in explorer and selecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/opening-a-folder-in-explorer-and-selecting-a-file)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programmatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer) might also help you out.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann: Your provided duplicate does not allow for multiple files to be selected.

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355/programmatically-select-multiple-files-in-windows-explorer

Comment: @Sefe  - I've edited the question. I would like to see the newly created files in that application instance as selected when I navigate to the folder path.

Comment: Have you checked the links in the comments?