# How to open explorer with multiple file selected

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i want to open explorer with multiple files selected.
For one file it is working fine with

```
  string argument = "/select, \"" + path + "\"";
  Process.Start("explorer.exe", argument);
```

but how to do for multiple files?

Comment: `explorer.exe /select` only takes 1 argument.

Comment: i know ,thats why i ask question here to find out some solution to my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Explorer with a specific file selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680415/how-to-open-explorer-with-a-specific-file-selected)

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/202449/explorer-exe-command-line-options-selecting-multiple-files .