# How to open a particular directory and SELECT a particular file there using C#

Tags: c#, .net

In my existing program, after completing some result I store it in a file.
I have the file(folder) path saved in a string var, 
I am seeking a way to open the same folder (not file directly) and in that explorer window, particular file must be selected!
so that user can come to know which file has been created by the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#, Open Folder and Select the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/c-open-folder-and-select-the-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

You pass `explorer.exe /select, filename`

[Opening a folder in explorer and selecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/c-open-folder-and-select-the-file)

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853) are some more command line options for explorer.exe

Answer (score 1):

And also look in to Process.Start Method.