# Highlight a file in Windows explorer window

Tags: c#, windows, file, explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#, Open Folder and Select the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/c-open-folder-and-select-the-file)

I want to do a search file function that opens the file folder and highlight the founded file. how can i highlight  the file (like a single mouse click on the file)?

Answer (score 2):

Start

`explorer.exe /select,Path/to/the/file`

For other explorer.exe command line options, see [this MSDN page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853) (Windows XP).

Comment: Link is dead. Here is an updated one: https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html