# Open file location

Tags: c#, winforms, file

When searching a file in Windows Explorer and right-click a file from the search results; there is an option: "Open file location". I want to implement the same in my C# WinForm. I did this:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)
{
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = new FileInfo(filePath).DirectoryName;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: What is the problem you face with your solution? if `openFileDialog_View` is an OpenFileDialog then you'll just get a dialog prompting a user to **open** a file.

Comment: I want any alternative and better way if any?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If `openFileDialog_View` is an [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) then you'll just get a dialog prompting a user to open a file. I assume you want to actually **open** the location in explorer.

You would do this:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", filePath);
}
```

---

To **select** a file `explorer.exe` takes a `/select` argument like this:

```
explorer.exe /select, <filelist>
```

I got this from an SO post: [Opening a folder in explorer and selecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/open-folder-and-select-the-file)

So your code would be:

```
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select, " + filePath);
}
```

Comment: this should be "explorer.exe"

Comment: nice Mr. gideon. but I want that file to be selected, How?

Comment: @H_wardak Updated my answer. A simple [google search](http://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=open%20explorer%20and%20select%20file&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=237055d012d02b32&ix=sea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1366&bih=643) landed me to that SO post.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it in my code. This will open the file directory in explorer and select the specified file just the way windows explorer does it.

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("explorer.exe", " /select, " + path);
}
```

Comment: is there any benefit if I using "ProcessStartInfo"? It's work without it also.

Comment: Yes this opens the folder but not any apps associated with the extension.  
For instance if its a file.kml it might try to open google earth but sometimes you just want the file folder to open