# How to Open file location based on grid view column's path? and also In a path I want to create a 'hyper link'

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

**Here is my Grid**

[image]

Based on the path i have to open a file location of the my path

My grid code look like this

```
<telerik:RadGridView  Grid.Row="7" 
                      Grid.Column="1" 
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                      ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                      Name="InventoryDetailsGrid"
                      Foreground="#357BCC"                                              
                      GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"> 
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

I tired to open based on the path open file location dialog box

**for example** :-
when I was click on the path I want look like same

[image]

I Can't find solution 
help me 
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646114/open-file-location)

Comment: @Anas In path I want to create a 'hyper link'

Comment: take a look at [DataGridViewLinkColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewlinkcolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2), maybe this what you are looking for

Comment: @Anas Im near to solve my issue but not yet and thank you for share this link

Comment: you're welcome,
please share your solution after you're done

Comment: with @Anas answer you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011407/how-to-handle-the-click-event-of-datagridviewlinkcolumn

Comment: @Anas  Finally I find the Solution

Comment: @Bharat Finally I find the Solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I find the solution

```
 <telerik:RadGridView  Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ShowGroupPanel="False" 
                                              Name="InventoryDetailsGrid"
                                              Foreground="#357BCC"                                              
                                              GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
                                              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                                <telerik:GridViewHyperlinkColumn Header="Path" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path}" />
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" Header="Title" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Size}" Header="Size" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding PathLength}" Header="Path Length" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding FileExtension}" Header="FileExtension" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding OfItem}" Header="Of Item" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>                          

</telerik:RadGridView>
```

It's Working for me yeah....