# How can I open Path and mark the file instead of open it?

Tags: c#, file, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Folder and Select the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/open-folder-and-select-the-file)

I have a path of a file.

I want to open its directory and mark him in the directory by clicking him.

I tried this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

and this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new FileInfo(Path).Directory.FullName);
```

Comment: You want to open the file explorer, with the file highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

How About

Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"c:\file.name");

Comment: thank you but it doesnt work this action open the file...a

Comment: success: string p = @"C:\tmp\this path contains spaces, and,commas\target.txt";
string args = string.Format("/e, /select, \"{0}\"", p);

ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "explorer";
info.Arguments = args;
Process.Start(info);