# How to select file in Explorer without creating unnecessary windows?

Tags: c#, explorer

This question shows how to open a new window of Windows Explorer and select a file in it: [Opening a folder in explorer and selecting a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/open-folder-and-select-the-file)

The problem with that approach is that every call creates a new Explorer window. Is there a way to use a window that is already opened in the location of our file and select it there?

Comment: Did your program open up the currently opened Explorer window?

Answer (score 0):

If you opened the original window you could use [Process.StandardInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) Property...
This allows you  to send additional commands to explorer window once it is already opened.

Comment: How do I reliably find out if it is open already? Or does this method not open unneeded windows automatically?

Comment: This method assumes you opened the window and that you know if you still have it opened.

Comment: StandardInput is meant for Console apps/input, not UI - I don't believe this will work..