# Is there any way to open file explorer and select a file from a UWP app?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

I can open file explorer from UWP apps using `Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync()` ([+](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/eae0b973-2ec6-4c2a-94fc-2a967095a9f2/uwpopening-file-explorer-from-windows-10-store-app?forum=wpdevelop)), but is there any way to *make a file selected* in that file explorer window?

There are [some ways to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334630/opening-a-folder-in-explorer-and-selecting-a-file) in Win32 apps which involve calling explorer.exe directly and passing parameters to it, which obviously won't work for UWP.

Comment: Launch a uri.Waitting to find.

Comment: @lindexi Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain more?

Comment: I writting a answer,please wait me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also use the `Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync` and use the second parameter `Folder​Launcher​Options` too.

`Folder​Launcher​Options` can make the file or folder that you want to select that use the `ItemsToSelect`.

`ItemsToSelect` is a read-only property, but you can add items to the existing list.

Here's an example, getting a folder using `FolderPicker` and then selecting all files:

The first is get the folder:

```
        FolderPicker p = new FolderPicker();
        p.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        StorageFolder folder = await p.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

And then get all files in the folder

```
   foreach (var temp in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
```

I can use FolderLauncherOptions to add the item that I want to select.

```
        var t = new FolderLauncherOptions();
        foreach (var temp in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
        {
            t.ItemsToSelect.Add(temp);
        }
```

Then open the file explorer

```
      await Launcher.LaunchFolderAsync(folder, t);
```

You can see that the explorer will be opened while selecting all files.

You can also add folders to the ItemsToSelect and it will be selected.

See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchFolderAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFolder_Windows_System_FolderLauncherOptions_

Comment: Thanks for `FolderLauncherOptions` and also the example you created.

Comment: @Mahdi Ghiasi The code can run in pc but I dont know why cant run in my mobile.

Comment: Weird, it works fine here on both PC and phone. I'm on Creators Update (build 15063) though. Which build are you on?

Comment: @Mahdi Ghiasi Good,laji ms.I think I should buy a new phone.

Comment: Or just enroll Insider Fast and get the creators update :)