# How can I check how many ms take for a downloadstring?

Tags: vb.net

How can I check how many ms is taking a timer to give back the value of a downloadstring using webclient?
Which kind of variable I should use in order to measure this?
i'm asking this because sometimes there are two possible solutions and I want to check the fastest one.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @24343424. Have you tried anything, yet? It can create a better discussion if you provide example code of what you have so far.

Comment: Start a StopWatch before calling `await [WebClient].DownloadDataTaskAsync()`, stop it when the awaited method returns. Not sure what *the fastest one* means. I'd go for HttpClient though.

Comment: I meant which way downloaded the html source faster and, thanks to stopwatch, I realize in average in better webclient than httpclient.